# convert this sentence to "not only but also"

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests, questions

> The sheepdog did not allow the tigers to lay their paw on sheep and tied them in a daisy chain.

Comment: I would not only like to meet that sheepdog but also to offer it a job.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for writing advice.

Answer (score 2):

My attempt at rewording the sentence a bit:

"Not only did the sheepdog stop the tigers from laying their paws on the sheep; it (or he/she if we know the gender) also tied them [I would repeat the object- the tigers - to avoid ambiguity. ...eg. also tied those sheep...) in a daisy chain"

Comment: First off, welcome to english.se. Thanks for adding an answer. I think if you review your answer, you'll notice it's nearly impossible to follow. You should look at the formatting tools and the preview of how your answer will look to make it clearer.

Comment: I'd use *keep* rather than *stop*: *"Not only did the sheepdog keep the tigers from laying their paws on the sheep, but it also tied them in a daisy chain."* To me, *keep* is better than *stop* because the sheepdog presumably kept the tigers away for an extended period.

Answer (score 0):

You mean

> The sheepdog did not only *not* allow the tigers to lay their paws on sheep, but also tied them in a daisy chain.

Comment: You changed the meaning or forgot a word... "The sheepdog did not only **not** allow the tigers..." or maybe "The sheepdog did not only disallow the tigers..."

Comment: Yup. Missed the meaning. Very strange sentence to begin with

Comment: I think **did not only not** is unbelievably clunky, and using italics for the second *not* doesn't really save it. Better by far would be *"Not only did the sheepdog not allow the tigers..."*. In such an obscure and verbose juxtaposition, I would also prefer to bin **but** completely, replace the comma with a semicolon, and follow it by a pronoun **he/she/it**.

Comment: I do not see me being able to start with "Not only" in combination with ", but also"

Answer (score 0):

The sheepdog **not only** didn't allow the tigers to lay their paws on sheep, **but also** tied them in a daisy chain.

Comment: Exactly what I'd go for.  Clean flow and removes ambiguity.

Comment: Don't use no double negatives. It's confusing.

Comment: It's not really a double negative. Replacing the two negatives with a positive renders the sentence nonsensical. **The sheepdog only allowed the tigers to lay their paws on sheep, but also tied them in a daisy chain.**

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to figure out the exact way to structure it without knowing exactly what the sentence means or is to mean.

> The sheepdog did not only *not* allow the tigers to lay their paw on sheep, but also tied them in a daisy chain.

Comment: See my comment on the other answer :) Missing a _not_ there :)

Comment: It's hard to know if that is the case. What does the sentence even mean? :)

Comment: The whole phrase I don't know, really. But the part "The sheepdog did not allow the tigers to lay their paw on sheep" seems unambiguously mean the the tigers were **not** allowed to touch the sheep, and your version explicitly states they _are_ allowed to do so. The second part of the sentence surely does not change the meaning like that :)

Comment: Ah yes, very true. I'd imagine the tigers weren't allowed to touch the sheep at all! :) The double negative "did not only not" is very bad phrasing though. S/he'd be better of rewording the whole thing.